# Best way to define optional setting keys in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

How should optional SettingKeys be handled in SBT?

Should I use SettingKey[Option[String]] or something else? And why?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a sensible default value indicating "absence", you could use that. Otherwise, yes, use `Option`, that's what it's for. A few standard keys in sbt use `Option` (e.g. `homepage`, `publishTo`).

If your key uses a sequence, you can use the empty sequence to denote absence.